# Trying to use an id from the same page that my .click function was triggered on, in an ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

newbie to coldfusion/jquery/programming general here. So the overview of my problem is this: I have a ticket id that corresponds with a specific row in my database. When I click a button, I would like one of the columns in that row to change values to "In Testing". My issue is that I do not know how to pull that ticket id number into my jquery function, or if this is even possible. My code:

```
<script src="/TicketFaster/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="/TicketFaster/js/scripts.js"></script>

<cfset ticketid="#ticketid#">

<button id="in_testing" type="button">In Testing</button>
```

my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#in_testing").click(function() {
    var x = (#ticketid#);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ticketcomponent.cfc?method=in_testing',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            test: x
        }
    });
});
});
```

The big problem is that these pages are being generated dynamically, so each one will have a different ticket id. Therefore, I need to have the ticket id variable be imported rather than just hard coded in to the jquery function. So is this possible? I did not include the query because it works fine when I use it in other places, just getting the data delivered is the tough part. I appreciate any help you can give me :)

Edit: I was requested to post what I'm trying right now. 
The original coldfusion is the same so I'm not going to post that again. Here is the js I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#in_testing").click(function() {
        var x = (<cfoutput>#ticketid#</cfoutput>);
        alert(x);
    });
});
```

(I also tried without the cfoutput tags)
As you can see, I'm just trying to do a simple alert to check if my variable has been correctly set. Once I get that to work, then the ajax should follow fairly quickly because I have some experience in that.

Comment: What happened when tried it? As long as you have a cfoutput around your variable in the JS it should work.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you want to update multiple tickets on the same page?

Comment: @MattBusche when I try it both with and without the cfoutput I get a js error.

Comment: And the error you get is what?

Comment: @AlexanderKwaschny I have one page for each ticket, so no multiple tickets on the same page. The end goal is to have multiple buttons to change the 'status' of a ticket. So if a developer is assigned a ticket to work on, he can mark it as 'in progress' or 'ready for review' or something like that.

Comment: @MattBusche the error I get with cfoutput tags is 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <', and without cfoutput tags I get simply 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'

Comment: Post the code you're trying in your original question

Comment: Alright just did @MattBusche

Answer (score 1):

What is your specific issue?, can you share a jsfiddle?

for dynamic events replace

```
$("#in_testing").click(function() {});
```

for

```
 $(document).on('click','#in_testing', function() {});
```

This value

```
 var x = (#ticketid#);
```

in jquery is some like that

```
 var x = $('#ticketid').val(); // for value or $('#ticketid') for object
```

you just have to take account id created dynamically

Comment: @ConorBaumgart - Just to clarify, `$('#ticketid').val();` assumes you have stored the value of `#ticketid#` in some element or field and assigned it an id of "ticketid". For example, as a hidden form field `<cfoutput><input type="hidden" id="ticketid" value="#ticketid#"></cfoutput>`

Comment: @BernandoBorunda awesome thank you, this worked! Is there a way to use jfiddle with coldfusion? I was under the impression it was only for html and js

Comment: And thank you for clarifying @Leigh, that step was a huge help and something I wouldn't have known to do. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @ConorBaumgart - Welcome.  *Is there a way to use jfiddle with coldfusion* For examples that can only be demonstrated with CF code, you can create a *limited* mix of CF and javascript on trycf.com. [For example](http://trycf.com/gist/2824ba62e94f905fa6e7/acf11?theme=monokai).  Though if is purely about jQuery, you will probably get a better response from jQuery folks if you hard code and stick to jFiddle (when possible).